# How many $7$-digit strings have the property that no adjacent digits are equal to each other, but the sum of all digits is odd?

Tags: combinatorics

A combination lock has $7$ digits, each of which can be any of $\{0, 1, 2, . . . , 9\}$. Combinations are allowed to start with $0$. How many of the combinations have the property that no adjacent digits are equal to each other, but the sum of all digits is odd?

For example, $1010102$ and $0123456$ would count, but $1010101$ and $1101020$ would not.

As of now, my thought process on solving this was to use induction on an $n$-digit combination lock as follows:

Base case: $n=1$. As we know that there is only one digit, it is trivial to see that no adjacent digits can be equal to each other. As such, there are $O_1 = 5$ combinations with an odd sum and $E_1 = 5$ combinations with an even sum.

IH: Assume there exists some $n$ such that we know $O_n$ and $E_n$

Inductive Step: Want to find $O_{n+1}$.

If we let the first $n$ digits of the lock be even, we know the rightmost digit must be odd, and vice versa. So we should be able to multiply $E_n$ by something and add $O_n$ multiplied by something else. Naively, I guessed that it would just be the number of possible odd/even values that ensure an odd sum, but the issue lies with the fact that the adjacent digits cannot be equal, but I cannot determine the parity of the second-to-last digit.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I'd do it this way:  Note that replacing each digit $x$ in a proposed combination by $9-x$ preserves the property that no two adjacent digits are equal, and reverses the parity of the digit sum.  Therefore, exactly half of the combinations that satisfy the adjacency constraint have an odd digit sum.  So use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to determine how many combinations (with no constraints on digit sum) have no adjacent digits that are equal, and then divide by $2$.

Comment: To the previous comment: we don't need to use inclusion and exclusion. We choose the first digit from 10 possible values and each next one from 9 possible values which leads us to the answer $10\cdot 9^6/2$

Comment: @SergeyZaitsev Which simplifies to $5 \cdot 9^6$.

Answer (score 2):

To collect both comments into an answer, first count the number of combinations that satisfy the adjacency constraint.  We have $10$ choices for the first digit and $9$ choices for each succeeding digit, so there are a total of $10 \cdot 9^6$ combinations that satisfy the adjacency constraint.

Now, note that since the string has odd length, replacing each digit $x$ in a proposed combination with $9-x$ preserves the property that the combination doesn't, or does, have at least two adjacent digits that are equal.  Note also that this replacement flips the parity of the digit sum.  It follows that exactly half of the combinations that satisfy the adjacency constraint have an odd digit sum.

Thus, there are $5 \cdot 9^6$ acceptable combinations.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You can't apply the same reasoning when the string has even length because subtracting each digit from $9$ doesn't flip the parity of the whole string's digit sum.